# "pause" and "resume" an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Not quite sure how to ask this question, or even how to search for it TBH. I have a live photo/text stream pushing to an array, so my page constantly has info coming in. So my page is constantly receiving new info at a pretty fast rate. I was wondering how or what to search for online to essentially "pause" and "resume" the ng-repeat while still maintaining the info pushing to the array so a counter and button such as "10 new photos" appears. I realize this may be a loaded question, but to keep it "simple", I'd just like to know how to pause ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the array in two.

```
$scope.items = []; //the visible model would be here
$scope.queue = []; //the pending-to-show elements are here
```

And we will assume that, when a new photo appears, it is pushed calling the following function (I don't know what's the actual event handler you have, so bear with this code as being it):

```
$scope.onReceiveItem = function(item)
{
    $scope.queue.push(item);
}
$scope.loadmore = function()
{
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.items, $scope.queue.splice(0, 10));
}
```

With this code you are doing:

1. your `onReceiveItem` will push on the queue, not in the actual displayable array.
2. `loadmore` is what you'd call on "10 more items". Will take 10 elements from the beginning of the queue, and append them via push to the actual array.

**Alternatively** if you want to do this depending on a `pause` functionality, you can:

```
$scope.onReceiveItem = function(item)
{
    if ($scope.pause) {
        $scope.queue.push(item);
    } else {
        if ($scope.queue.length) {
            //resuming queued items when unpaused and new items arrive
            Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.items, $scope.queue.splice(0, $scope.queue.length));
        }
        $scope.items.push(item);
    }
}
```

and the other function would be the same.

**Disclaimer**: I don't know how do you get the data, so I just gave you the functions. They live in the `$scope` but it may not be needed depending on your case.

**General good practices**: It is almost 100% safe to assume that the `items` array, when changed, will reflect its value to the view, as if the $digest/$apply process was pure magic. *Is good practice to not relay on such internals* for the most common cases. If you want both "live data" and "dead data", you should have two different data structures; ask yourself "which data is live and which data is not?" and you will have two data sets. `$scope.queue` is not needed to be in the `$scope` at all - I put it there for clarity- but just be a reachable identifier in the same lexical scope (note I did not use the $ here because I'm talking about the programming concept), like `var queue = [];` in the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the pause but you can use some thing like limit to 10.
like the code below probably. U can bind the limitTo value rather than hardcoding it.
and then you can update the value from your code when needed.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items|limitTo:10">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "simple" answer, you might want to change up the code a bit or the functionality.

Angular uses a digest loop that checks if any of the variables in the scope have changed since the last time it's run. This allows it to run a dirty check and update the variables it's binding between the view and the model/controller.

What you're asking then, is, "how to I pause Angular's digest loop and start it again once I know enough things have changed?". You'll have to update scope variables outside the regular loop and then call $apply when you actually want it to check.

Off the top of my head, the way I'd work around it is have a second array that feeds into he array ng-repeat is hooked up to. You have a variable, let's call it $scope.show, that gets set to false when pause is clicked and true when resume is clicked. Your feed pushes to the secondary array then pushes to the ng-repeat array if $scope.show is true. Additionally, on switch of $scope.show to true, immediately push everything from the feed array into the ng-repeat array that isn't there. You can also base a variable such as $scope.diff off the difference between the length of the secondary and the ng-repeat array. This would be the number of "new" photos.